# check if div has class then animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do an `animate` after an `owl carousel drag` user action.

The problem is that `$(this)` is not recognizing the `.nav-item` that has `.active` class. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
  if ($(".nav-item").hasClass("active")) {
    var navPosition = $('.navbar-collapse').scrollLeft()
    elemPosition = $(this).offset().left;
    $(".navbar-collapse").animate({scrollLeft: navPosition + elemPosition}, 800);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `hasClass` doesn't select an element, but it just returns true or false.
To do what you need to do, try using the `each` function to select the element you want to interact with and assign it to `this` correctly:

```
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
  $(".nav-item").each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")){
      var navPosition = $('.navbar-collapse').scrollLeft();
      elemPosition = $(this).offset().left;
      $(".navbar-collapse").animate({scrollLeft: navPosition + elemPosition}, 800);
    }
  }
});
```

You could also do something like this in order to select the elements with the active class with one single selector string:

```
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
  $(".nav-item.active").each(function(){
    var navPosition = $('.navbar-collapse').scrollLeft();
    elemPosition = $(this).offset().left;
    $(".navbar-collapse").animate({scrollLeft: navPosition + elemPosition}, 800);
  }
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/each/